# Is it possible to use string::find to detect a new line character?

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I am trying to parse a string of 1200 songs and I would like to set my barCount to 0 every time I find a '\n' or my barCount =4.  From what I have found online, \n represents one character, but I'm not sure what to do with that information... How can I find it, and then do what I need to do?

```
int barCount = 0;
size_t start = 0;
size_t n = 0;
int charCount = 0;
while((start = chartDataString.find(" |", start)) != string::npos){         
        ++barCount;
        start+=2;
        charCount++;
        //if(barCount == 3){//  || chartDataString.find("]")){
    if(chartDataString.find("\n") !=string::npos){
        barCount = 0;
    }
    else if(barCount == 4  || chartDataString[charCount] == ']') {
        chartDataString.insert(start, "\n");
        barCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you provided? Does it work? If not, what's the problem?

Comment: I think you need to start searching after all the characters you've already found.  ie `chartDataString.find("\n", start)`

Comment: I don't know that it's working... since I am in a while loop, I would like it to keep going through, so if we see a \n, barCount = 0, if on the next character we see | I want to increase my barCount... but the barCount isn't been adjusted

Comment: Have tried debugging the code? Seeing what happens step by step will surely lead you to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, I suspect I understand what you're trying to do now.  Let me see if I get this straight:

- Each song title/record in your string consists of up to four fields separated by vertical bars
- A record may be terminated early by a right-bracket or a newline
- If it's not terminated by a newline, insert one.

The following may do a better job:

```
size_t curr_pos = 0, next_bar, next_nl, next_brk;
int    bar_count = 0;

while (true)
{
    next_bar = chartDataString.find(" |", curr_pos);
    next_nl  = chartDataString.find("\n", curr_pos);
    next_brk = chartDataString.find("]",  curr_pos);

    if (next_bar == string::npos &&
        next_nl  == string::npos &&
        next_brk == string::npos)
        break;

    // Is a newline the next thing we'll encounter?
    if (next_nl < next_bar && next_nl < next_brk)
    {
        curr_pos  = next_nl + 1;  // skip past newline
        bar_count = 0;            // reset bar count
    }

    // Is a vertical bar the next thing we'll encounter?
    if (next_bar < next_nl && next_bar < next_brk)
    {
        bar_count++;
        curr_pos = next_bar + 2;  // skip past vertical bar    
    }

    // Is a right-bracket the next thing we'll encounter?
    if (next_brk < next_bar && next_brk < next_nl)
    {
        bar_count = 4;            // fake like we've seen all 4 bars
        curr_pos = next_brk + 1;  // skip past bracket
    }

    // Have we seen 4 vertical bars or a right bracket?
    if (bar_count == 4)
    {
        bar_count = 0;
        chartDataString.insert("\n", curr_pos);
        curr_pos += 1;             // skip the newline we just inserted
    }
}
```

It's a little more verbose, but it tries to break apart all the different conditions.  Hopefully, this helps.